# HP Scanjet Enterprise 8500 fn1 fails when sending scanned document to sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

Please does any one knows why HP Scanjet Enterprise 8500 fn1 scanner fails when sending multiple scanned pages in pdf format like 25pages to SharePoint 2010 but when sending scan pages that is about 5pages it was success.

Answer (score 0):

How big is the 25 pages PDF file? It might be possible that the upload fails due to upload size limitations.

The maximum upload size for a web application can be configured using Central Administration > General Settings > Web Application General Settings > Maximum Upload size.

Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: TempaC Thank you very much for quick response. The file size of the pdf is just 3 megabytes which I don't think is too big to upload to SharePoint since the maximum upload size for SharePoint is 50mb. Though I scanned the same document to  a network shared folder it was successful and fails when scanned to SharePoint. please do you have any other information that could help me resolving this issue. thank you for you help.

Comment: How are the files sent from the scanner to SharePoint? Is it done via e-mail?